# Hive Serde Regex not recognizing string pattern

Tags: regex, hive

Here are two lines from my log files that I'm trying to match. I'm trying to separate each line into four columns (date, hostname, command, status). 
The line is tab deliminated between date, hostname, command, and status in the line. The status column may contain spaces.

```
03-24-2014      fm506      TOTAL-PROCESS   OK;HARD;1;PROCS OK: 717 processes
03-24-2014      fm504      CHECK-LOAD      OK;SOFT;2;OK - load average: 54.61, 56.95
```

In Rubular (http://rubular.com/) my regex expression matches exactly as I want it; however after I query my hive table for the date column, I get the entire line which leads me to believe that the regex statement doesn't match what HIVE is looking for.

([^ ]*)\s*([^ ]*)\s*([^ ]*)\s*(.*)

And this is my create table statement with results from select query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sys_results(
date STRING
,hostname STRING
,command STRING
,status STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "([^ ]*)\\s*([^ ]*)\\s*([^ ]*)\\s*(.*)",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION  '/user/sys_log_output/sys-results/';


select date from sys_results;
03-24-2014      fm506      TOTAL-PROCESS   OK;HARD;1;PROCS OK: 717 processes
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. hive regex recognizes tabs using '\t' I changed my input.regex expression to this. 
    "input.regex" = "([^ ]*)\t([^ ]*)\t([^ ]*)\t([^ ].*)"